# Why isn't RDNSS working on Windows 10 post Creators Update

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp, ipv6

I have configured RDNSS on my router with an IPv6 DNS Server, however windows is not receiving this, I am not running DHCPv6 and only running DHCPv4, why am I not receiving DNS? According to [This Article](https://insinuator.net/2017/05/one-step-closer-rdnss-rfc-8106-support-in-windows-10-creators-update/) it should be supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When disabling IPv4 on the interface I immediately received IPv6 DNS information via RDNSS, it seems that if you run DHCPv4 on your IPv4 Stack the Windows OS also expects you to distribute DNS via DHCPv6.  This may be a bug but if you run DHCPv4 you'll need DHCPv6 to provide IPv6 DNS information.  This also seems limited to the interface (DHCPv4 on the wireless does not prevent RDNSS adverts on LAN)

This is not an issue on Fedora 25.